# Ubuntu not booting properly, or mounting properly... or installing updates properly

Tags: boot, updates, mount

For the past couple days, following an attempt to update the OS, my computer shows this on boot-up:

[image]

The only reason I'm using it right now is that I booted up from an older version, but I've had problems with installing new version before, and also getting error messages like this:

[image]

I believe I've also had problems removing old ones through the terminal.

Anyways, what's the best route at this point?

### EDIT:

Understanding it as a kernel panic, I managed to get some info on my boot files. Here's what came up.

```
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .
```

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext2
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg
```

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       crypto_LUKS
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info:
```

ubuntu-vg-root': _______________________________________________________________

```
File system:       
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

ubuntu-vg-swap_1': _____________________________________________________________

```
File system:       
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

mount: unknown filesystem type ''

`============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       499,711       497,664  83 Linux
/dev/sda2             501,758 1,953,523,711 1,953,021,954   5 Extended
/dev/sda5             501,760 1,953,523,711 1,953,021,952  83 Linux


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt mLMv6i-emLW-vtk7-IRqk-QNrh-WhXk-VLqRFf LVM2_member 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 5077026c-b631-4601-b0e9-fc228c6860e9   ext4       
/dev/sda1        8fb7c16b-f131-4622-86f0-e3a54e5272c3   ext2       
/dev/sda5        37bfa81a-5253-4b9e-bfb3-963476e52b17   crypto_LUKS 

========================= "ls -R /dev/mapper/" output: =========================

/dev/mapper:
control
sda5_crypt
ubuntu--vg-root
ubuntu--vg-swap_1

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda1        /boot                    ext2       (rw)


============================= sda1/grub/grub.cfg: ==============================`

### Specs:

- Memory: 3.9 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU Q8300 @ 2.50GHz × 4
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on NV96
- OS: 64-bit
- Disk: 980.1 GB (and yet it says I don't have enough space in boot)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the 'ol linux images were cluttered. [Followed advice made on a similar topic, guiding me through the proper way to uninstall outdated installing packages.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1751574)